# MySQL — ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only when both unique fields match, else INSERT

Tags: mysql, primary-key, multiple-columns, unique-index, on-duplicate-key

I have the following query:

```
"INSERT INTO `occ_apps` (`occ_date`, `service_tag`, `counter`) VALUES (?, ?, '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counter` = (`counter`+1)"
```

Currently it's incrementing the `counter` when either `occ_date` or `service_tag` is matching in a row.
Where `occ_date` and `service_tag` are `unique` fields, and I can't set primary key to both unique fields.

I ran the following:

```
ALTER TABLE occ_apps
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (occ_date, service_tag);
```

And I get, the error:

```
`#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`
```

I want it to update (increment) the counter only when `occ_date` and `service_tag` both matches (already exists) in a single row, otherwise it should insert a new row.

`Software version: 5.5.53-MariaDB-1~wheezy - mariadb.org binary distribution`

when I ran `DESC occ_apps` I get:

```
Field           Type            Null        Key     Default     Extra

serial_no       int(255)        NO          PRI     NULL          auto_increment
occ_date        varchar(255)    NO          UNI     NULL        
counter         int(255)        NO                  NULL    
service_tag     varchar(255)    YES         UNI     NULL
```

Comment: `ADD UNIQUE KEY (occ_date, service_tag)` this should help you.

Comment: Can you share `desc occ_apps` results.

Comment: @KeyurShah always better to ask for SHOW CREATE TABLE instead

Comment: @KeyurShah Updated the question with result of `desc occ_apps`

Comment: what exactly is your counter supposed to hold?

Comment: @e4c5 an integer, that'll increment if duplicates are found.

Comment: in that case its' not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you even need a counter field in your table. It looks like your counter is merely holding how many times a given value occurs. And that's something that can be generated easily using a GROUP BY

```
SELECT occ_date, COUNT(*) FROM occ_apps GROUP BY `occ_date`;
```

So you want to filter the query so that you get only items with at least 5 counts?

```
SELECT occ_date, COUNT(*) FROM occ_apps  WHERE service_tag = 'service-1'
GROUP BY `occ_date` HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

These sorts of problems have been solved millions of times using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). This is just the tip of  the ice berge as far as what SQL query aggregation can do. Please take a moment to read up on it.

Comment: While fetching, I need to `SELECT` `occ_date` where `counter` > 5 `AND` `service_tag` = `service-1`. That's why I need to increment the `counter` for same date and same service, i.e. only when `occ_date` and `service_tag` both already exists in a single row, else `INSERT` new row.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected, I didn't know I could it in this way as well. Thanks for your patience and effort!! May your business grows quickly!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Thank you for your kind comments. All the best with your project